# Adding a coordinate point marker in sympy Python

Tags: python, sympy

I want to put a marker on the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6 which I repeat from numpy arrange. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128588/how-to-add-markers-at-certain-x-coordinates-using-sympy-plot), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963745/how-to-plot-the-points-of-a-set-of-integers-on-a-number-line-graph-of-a-one-vari) it is already there for learning materials, but it doesn't work as well as I want.

Can anyone help me with this problem, any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, plot
from sympy.plotting import plot 
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
ekpr =  x**2
a = np.arange(1, 7, 1)
for sol in a:
   if sol <= 6:
       print(sol)

plot(
    ekpr.rewrite(Add), xlim=[0, 8],
        markers=[{
            "args": [sol, [0], a], # coordinates of the point
            "marker": "o" # the type of marker to use
       }]
```

)

The result is like this [image: picture].

Why is it that only one coordinate point is all blue? And I expect the coordinates to be all blue following the number 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib requires coordinates, namely x-component and y-component.

When you call the `plot` function and create `markers`, you need to tell it what are your coordinates. Let's see what you did:

```
"args": [sol, [0], a]
```

Here, you told matplotlib to place a marker at coordinate (6, 0), but then matplotlib loop over `a`: let `ai` be the ith element of `a`, Matplotlib will place a marker at the coordinate (ai, ai). Hence, you can see in your picture the orange line.

Instead, you need to provide `a` as the x-coordinate and 0 as the y-coordinate. But, since `a` is an iterable (array, or list, or tuple, ...), then y-coordinate must also be an iterable. So, `[0] * len(a)` is going to create a list of zeros with as many elements as `a`.

```py
plot(
    ekpr.rewrite(Add), xlim=[0, 8],
        markers=[{
            "args": [a, [0] * len(a)], # coordinates of the point
            "marker": "o", # the type of marker to use
            "linestyle": "none"
       }]
)
```